# Should I SCP my node_modules folder in continuous deployment setup?

Tags: node.js, scp, codeship

I'm building my first continuous deployment setup using [codeship.io](http://codeship.io) to deploy to my [Digital Ocean](http://digitalocean.com) droplet. Codeship's documentation suggests using SCP to clone the production files.

My question is: should I include the `node_modules` folder in the clone? Or should I figure out some way to `npm install` on the droplet when needed?

Comment: You'll probably spend less time just using SCP, plus you get  the added stability of always having the same version of dependencies in your deployment.

Comment: Okay, thanks @remus. I just didn't want to go ahead and do something that was completely frowned on for whatever reason.